# Smooth scrolling across browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to make scrolling smooth across browsers? I have tried many things but nothing seems to be working... here is what I am currently using for the body

```
body {
    color: #4A4A4A;
    background-color: #191E25;

    font-family: 'arial'; arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Everything I found was plugins for parallax scrolling or scrolling for one page website with navigation. But I only want a smooth scrolling for the whole site across browsers. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [jquery.nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll). It offers a lot of customization and downgrades nicely. Just add this to your pages:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").niceScroll();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use plugin tho mate

Comment: There is no way to get cross platform smooth scrolling with just css. The only css I'm aware of that does such a thing is -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; which you are already using, but as you know, doesn't work in many browsers. The only solution is javascript and the easiest solution is using a plugin.